# como quitar la direcion de envio en boton de paypal?

Tags: html

alguna forma de quitarle la direcion de envio a este Boton de paypal?

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>
  <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
  <input type='hidden' name='business' value='miemail@dominio.com'>
  <input type='hidden' name='lc' value=''>
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='CONCEPTO_PAYPAL"'>
  <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='25'>
  <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
  <input type='hidden' name='button_subtype' value='services'>
  <input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='0'>
  <input type='hidden' name='bn' value='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest'>
<p><input type='submit' value='Pagar Ahora' name='submit' /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: hay una variable escondida que NO se cual es necesito es QUITAR LA DIRECCION DE ENVIO pero no conozco cual es esa variable. no se leer la API paypal y cuando creo el boton de pagos entrando a paypal.com no sale igual

Comment: Encontré una explicación en PayPal aquí: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/
Todavía estoy leyendola.

Comment: yo tambien creo que lo encontre ahora a crear y creo que se agrega esto <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>

Comment: Si descubres como hacerlo sería útil que te respondas a ti mismo a si todos nos beneficiamos de esa búsqueda.

Comment: si creo saber cual es es una variable que consegui en la misma web. seria cuestion que alguien la confirme ahora buscare el boton de suscriptores

Answer (score 0):

Solo agregar al script dentro del Form

```
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
```